# error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘_mm256_extract_epi64’: target specific option mismatch

Tags: c, compiler-errors, intel, clion, avx

Im trying to use avx intrinsics in C, using CLion.
Even though I included `avxinttin.h` in the header, the definitions of it are not included and I get an error message for all avx functions.

I get this UI message when hovering over the avx functions:
[image]

Comment: `#include <immintrin.h>`, not stuff like `avxinttin.h` directly.  And obviously compile with `-march=x86-64-v3` to enable AVX2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also included <immintrin.h>. But where do I have to include the compiler instruction? In the make file?

Comment: Post a [mre] of how you compile your code. If you use plain makefiles, you would typically create a CFLAGS variable where you add the necessary options and then add `$(CFLAGS)` to your compile rules.